# PHP insert br tag after 2nd Word of a Given String

Tags: php, arrays, string, join, slice

I'm trying to insert `<br/>` tag after 2nd word of a given string, but it crops some words of my string, can anyone help to fix the code on this

```
$pos = 1;
$string  = 'Lorem Imsem Dollar Country';
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$new_array = array_slice($words, 0, $pos, true) +
    array($pos => '<br/>') +
    array_slice($words, $pos, count($words) - 1, true) ;
$new_string = join(" ",$new_array);
echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) :

```
$pos = 1;
$string  = 'Lorem Imsem Dollar Country';
$words = explode(" ", $string);
array_splice( $words, $pos, 0, '<br>' );
$new_string = join(" ",$words);
echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

With $pos you can select the position of the `<br/>` tag.

Use `$pos = 2` to add the tag after second position

```
$pos = 2;
$string  = 'Lorem Imsem Dollar Country';
$words = explode(" ", $string);
array_splice( $words, $pos, 0, '<br>' );
$new_string = join(" ",$words);
echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

With preg_replace:

```
$new = preg_replace("/^(([^ ]+ ){2})/",'$1<br/>', $string);
```